# vibrating each atom in a structure?

Tags: modifiers, parent

I am trying to make a structure containing lots of vibrating atoms. I already created the structures by first creating a cube and a small sphere. And, then choosing the particle properties of the cube and using the usual steps of being in the emitter tab, selecting the sphere in the rendering section. But now I want all the atoms to vibrate. I am very new to blender. Please let me know how I can achieve that. Thanks
[image]

Comment: I would use geometry nodes to do this

Comment: To add to Blender Starter's answer, if you use keyframes, don't forget, for the emitter, to enable the Particle > Render > Object > Global Coordinates option

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you two ways to do this.In particle system set the emission velocity to 0 so that they are stationary then use a force field called turbulence (you would need to play with the values for the desired effect) or you can convert the particles to mesh and animate them. To do that go to modifier tab while the object is selected choose convert . Now hide the old particle system , select all individual particles and insert a single keyframe (only location) . Then go to graph editor and choose noise modifier (play with the values till you like it).